# how to test reducers with jest

Tags: jestjs, redux-saga

I have this reducer:

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { DEFAULT_ACTION, SOURCES_LOADED, SOURCES_REQUEST } from './constants';

export const initialState = fromJS({
  sources: null,
  loading: false
});

function appReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOURCES_REQUEST:
      return state
        .set('loading', true);
    case SOURCES_LOADED:
      return state
        .set('sources', action.payload.sources)
        .set('loading', false);
    case DEFAULT_ACTION:
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default appReducer;
```

and this tests:

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import reducer from '../reducer';
import * as types from '../constants';

describe('application reducers', () => {
  it('should return the initial state', () => {
    expect(reducer(undefined, {})).toEqual(fromJS(
      {
        sources: null,
        loading: false
      }
    ));
  });

  it('should handle the sources request', () => {
    expect(reducer({ loading: true }, {
      type: types.SOURCES_REQUEST
    })).toEqual(fromJS({ loading: true }));
  });
});
```

the second test is failing:

```
TypeError: state.set is not a function

      11 |     case SOURCES_REQUEST:
      12 |       return state
    > 13 |         .set('loading', true);
         |          ^
      14 |     case SOURCES_LOADED:
      15 |       return state
      16 |         .set('sources', action.payload.sources)
```

How can I add the test to these reducers, since this is redux sagas and I am following this https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests due to it is the documentation I found which is closer to my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer expects the `state` it receives to be an `immutable` object.

But in your second test you pass it a plain javascript object, which does not have the `.set` method you try to call.

```js
it('should handle the sources request', () => {
  expect(reducer(fromJS({
    loading: true
  }), {
    type: types.SOURCES_REQUEST
  })).toEqual(fromJS({
    loading: true
  }));
});
```

or in this particular case you could pass it `undefined` and the reducer would use the `initialState`

Comment: could you possibly answer this  (its related to reducers testing also): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72463260/test-conditional-inside-reducer-switch-in-react