# test conditional inside reducer switch in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, redux

Here i have a reducer which i'm testing at the moment, in my test coverage it shows Uncovered Line : this part 'return action.payload;' which is inside 'changeNode' function, any advice on how to test if else ? (i have many cases inside my switch and few of them have if else, if i solve this one i could solves those others easily)

```js
export function graphArticle(
  state = initialGraph,
  action: graphArticle
) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case ActionType.EDIT_NODE:
      const changeN = (n: any) => {
        if (n.id == action.payload.id) {
          return action.payload;
        } else {
          return n;
        }
      };
      return {
        ...state,
        graph: {
          ...state.graph,
          cameras: updateGraphC(state.graph, action.payload),
          model: {
            ...state.graph.model,
            nodes: state.graph.model?.nodes.map(changeN),
          },
          currentNode: changeN(state.currentNode),
        },
      };
      }
```

test:

```js
 it("EDIT_NODE ", () => {
        expect(
          reducers.graphArticle(undefined, {
            type: ActionType.EDIT_NODE,
            payload: {
              analyser_id: "yureg",
              id: 6,
            },
          })
        ).toEqual({
          floorplan: "",
          graph: {
            cameras: [],
            currentNode: "",
            model: {
              nodes: undefined,
            },
          },
        });
      });
```

Comment: Just a FYI as you say you are currently learning: You are learning an extremely outdated style of Redux here. Modern Redux does not have switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, immutable reducer logic with spreads or connect/mapStateToProps. I'd recommend to read [Why RTK is Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and go with the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) to learn Redux.

Comment: @phry place where i am working, they use this outdated style of Redux, and that file is very large, so i have to test it, at the moment i have already tested 70%, those left are if elses, and dont know how to test if there is conditions inside cases

Comment: any advice/help is appreciated

Comment: what is in the `initialGraph` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your test does not actually test the "edit" functionality of the reducer, as you are testing against the initial state, which has no nodes.

You need to provide an initial state, *currently the `undefined` you pass to `reducers.graphArticle`*, with a couple of nodes, and then pass an action as the other parameter that will edit one of them, so that the test will go through the `if` and the `else`.

Something like

```js
it("EDIT_NODE ", () => {
  const stateToEdit: InitialGraph = {
    floorplan: "",
    currentNode: "",
    graph: {
      cameras: [],
      model: {
        nodes: [{
          id: 1,
          analyser_id: "first"
        }, {
          id: 6,
          analyser_id: 'original'
        }, ],
      },
    },
  };
  const resultingStateAfterEdit: InitialGraph = {
    floorplan: "",
    currentNode: "",
    graph: {
      cameras: [],
      currentNode: "",
      model: {
        nodes: [{
          id: 1,
          analyser_id: "first"
        }, {
          id: 6,
          analyser_id: 'yureg'
        }, ],
      },
    },
  };

  expect(
    reducers.graphArticle(stateToEdit, {
      type: ActionType.EDIT_NODE,
      payload: {
        analyser_id: "yureg",
        id: 6,
      },
    })
  ).toEqual(resultingStateAfterEdit);
});
```

Comment: code is working fine, i can edit nodes without any error, but need to have test for it

Comment: @walee, the `currentNode` existing both inside and outside of `graph` confused me. I updated the before/after variables in my answer.

Comment: thank you very much it worked, but if you have time could you explain this: 'You need to provide an initial state, currently the undefined' i did as this man is doing and he also did not have https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frPOH0rv_F8

Comment: @walee that is becuase in their sample app, the initial state already contains a default TODO and they perform the action on that. Your tests need to be relevant to your own specific needs.